# Python 3: igraph does not generate any image

Tags: python-3.x, igraph, directed-graph

I am trying this

```
g = ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(100, 0.1);
ig.plot(g)
```

I have got no message and no image.
Does someone know what is happening?

**Edit**
Cairo Library is installed.
My system is ubuntu 16.04
This line of code below generates the image with a pdf

```
    ig.plot(g, "teste.pdf")
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial that tells you the steps you should follow. http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html - Specifically, here is the plotting section: http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#drawing-a-graph-using-a-layout

Comment: You mean that I should install the Cairo Library? I have it installed Version 1.10. I could not find anymore information for ubuntu systems.